# Search the name in the excel document

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have this excel document like this

```
id    | Name   |  Address | Other | 
-----------------------------------
#1    | xxxx   |  xxxx    | xxxx  |
#2    | yyyy   |  yyyy    | yyyy  |
```

Now I need to search the **name field** in the excel doc with the **user entered string**

**For Example**

User enter text---> **xxxx**

> I want to search the string with the name field in the excel
>   document

if it present means show the msg box..
how can I make this with C#.net
Any One help me

Comment: You just want to search the excel and show the message box ? Or you want to edit any value too ?

Comment: i want to search the word in the excel document(only in Name field) with text given by user in textbox...if it present means show message..

Comment: @GOPI.. I have added an answer. Please check and let me know if that answers your query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to export the Excel file to .csv (comma separated values). Then you can read it line by line, split the line by the comma character and check if the 2nd element (index 1) contains what you're searching for. 2nd element, because your Name column is the second column.

```
string searched="yourname";

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.csv"))
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] splitLine = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        if (splitLine[1]=="yourname") // or .Contains("yourname")
            return true;
    }
}
```

Didn't test the code, but it should work.

Comment: If possible, saving the file as a CSV will be easiest. This code should work fine, however just be aware if the file is using text separators. If it is, it would be possible that commas could appear in a column which would require a slightly more complex split

Comment: Search can be used for Excel(.xls/.xlsx) files also?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to read the entire excel file to a datatable and then search the datatable.

Please pardon me as I have limited knowledge in LINQ.

```
// You can change C:\Members.xlsx to any valid path 
// where the file is located.

string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #a31515; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'">
                Data Source=C:\Members.xlsx;Extended
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #a31515; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'">
                Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""; 
// if you don't want to show the header row (first row) in the grid
// use 'HDR=NO' in the string

string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
excelConnection.Open(); // this will open an Excel file
OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL,excelConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand);

// create data table

DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);

// bind the datasource

dataBingingSrc.DataSource = dTable;
// assign the dataBindingSrc to the DataGridView
```

dgvExcelList.DataSource = dataBingingSrc;

```
// dispose used objects
```

dTable.Dispose()
    dataAdapter.Dispose();
    dbCommand.Dispose();
    excelConnection.Close();
    excelConnection.Dispose();

Then you can search the dTable as per your requirement. A sample search is as given below

```
string strExpr = null;

strSearch = "Name LIKE  'Pet%'";

DataRow[] Rows = null;

Rows = dTable.Select(strSearch);


for (i = 0; i <= Rows.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
    MessageBox.Show(Row(i)(0).ToString());

}
```

Please let me know of improvements.